# $element.css('top') returning different value to $element.position().top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I’m trying to extract the position of an element and I’ve realised the CSS properties of `left` and `top` return different values to `$element.position().left` or `$element.position().top`.

The `<div>` I’m trying to track is positioned absolutely:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

.target {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 12%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="target">
  </div>
</div>
```

So `$('.target').css('top')` returns `'12%'` and `$('.target').position().top` is returning `0`.

Is this difference expected or is there something I’m missing? The element in my project is clearly **not** positioned at 0, 0!

And, more to the point, why are **both** the position().top and position().left properties returning 0 when, given the element's final rendered position on screen, one of those properties should be non-zero?

Answer (score 1):

The `css('top')` returns the `css` directive `top` if it is set.

While `position().top` returns the calculated `top` position.

I you are having a `top position` to `0`, it is because your `container` does not have a `height` defined which is the "normal" behavior with `bootstrap`.

Even if, you have a `position: absolute`, on your `target`.

To have a `top position` to be `12%` of your `container`'s height, you have to fix the `container`' height, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  console.log($(".target").position().top);

});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}

.target {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 12%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="target">
    aaa
  </div>
</div>
```

To have a `top position` to be `12%` of the document, you have to use a `position: fixed` on the `target`, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  console.log($(".target").position().top);

});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.target {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0%;
  top: 12%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="target">
    aaa
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what does 'the calculated top position' mean? Is that the 'end result' of any and all positioning? If so, in my example, these results should still be the same, shouldn't they?

Comment: "calculated" means "rendered". This is the position when the browser ends the rendering of your element.

Comment: @moosefetcher Since your `container` have no height (so `height = 0`), `12%` of `zero` makes `0` for its `top` position, even if `position: absolute`.

Comment: I've added in the css rules that effectively exist in my actual project. I still get 0 from position().top.

Comment: @moosefetcher Look at the updated answer with snippets.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I've tried changing the positioning to fixed and it had unexpected sizing results; The bigger project slightly depends on it being positioned absolutely and I'm not sure I want to jump down the rabbit-hole of changing that.

Answer (score 0):

Like ADreNaLiNe-DJ just said the `css('top')` return the `css` directive `top`, in your case 12%, while `position().top` return the calculated `top` position.

You must define an `height` or a `padding` to your parent container to see a value different from 0 using `position().top`

Comment: In my actual project, the parent container has both a set height and 0 padding, but the problem persists. The .target div is clearly not being rendered at 0% top position - there is a space between the element and the top of the screen.

Comment: Can you provide us a Fiddle or a live demo of your project? Even just the problematic code portion

Comment: I've tried to keep the example as simple as possible. The actual problem is a positioning bug on iPhone, when viewed in portrait. I've got css that effectively rotates the containing view so the app is always viewed as landscape. This seems to be messing up how I position a separate element based on the position of the '.target' div. I can't link to a live demo due to client restrictions, sorry. Even with the rotation, though, I don't understand why $div.position() top and left are both returning 0.

Comment: Maybe you can refresh the calculation of the position when device is rotated

Comment: I can tell that the position calculation is already being made AFTER the rotation, because the conditional to use alternate positioning (to account for the iPhone bug) checks the css transform property to see if it's rotated.

Comment: Instead of `position().top` you can use `offset().top`, the difference is that `position()` is relative to the offset parent, while `offset()` is relative to the document. The final solution can be tricky, but these are the problems to face up with devices bugs.

Comment: Even using offset(), both .top and .left return 0 values. I don't get that at all. Surely one of them should be non-zero...